# How to select the first letters in a case-insensitive context?

Tags: mysql, sorting, unicode, collation

I have a table like this:

```
id | name 
----------------
 1 | àbbot
 2 | about
 3 | zorro
```

I want to select the first letters in a case-insensitive context, like this:

```
let
----------
a
z
```

But any of those, with any unicode collation, gives the same wrong result:

```
SELECT LOWER(SUBSTR(name,1,1)) AS let FROM t GROUP BY let

SELECT LOWER(SUBSTR(name,1,1)) AS let FROM t GROUP BY letter ORDER BY let ASC

SELECT * FROM
     (SELECT LOWER(SUBSTR(name,1,1)) AS let FROM t ORDER BY let DESC) AS x
GROUP BY let ORDER BY let ASC
```

Wrong result:

```
let
----------
à
z
```

Is there a way to fix the ordering, without casting? (because I have to cover non-Latin languages too, such as Japanese).

Maybe I have an old version of MySQL... Can you test queries in your environment, please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, found a solution

```
SELECT UPPER(SUBSTR(name,1,1)) AS let FROM 
    (SELECT name FROM t ORDER BY name DESC) AS x
GROUP BY let ORDER BY let ASC
```

Comment: You should delete your question in this case - given it has no other comments, answers, or votes.

Comment: It's 10 minutes old. Forsooth.

Comment: maybe can be useful to someone. better solutions are welcome too. for example, if there is a way to specify a collation for an alias (in my example 'let')